# Prove that the point of intersection of diagonals of a rhombus is centre of the circle inscribed in it

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

> Prove that the point of intersection of diagonals of a rhombus is centre of the circle inscribed in it

Let's assume that $E$ is the centre of the circle and $C$ is the point of intersection of the diagonals. If we prove that $\angle CFB'=\angle EFB'$ we can prove that points $C$ and $E$ coincide.

We know that $\angle  ACB'=90^{\circ}$ from the properties of a rhombus. Let $\angle ACB'=x$ and $\angle CAB'=90-x$. We need to prove that $\angle FCB'=\angle CAB'=90-x$. Since the sum of angles in a triangle is $180$ degrees, $\angle CFB'=90$ degrees. I don't know how to proceed further.

[image]

Comment: It's probably easier to prove that any rhombus can be created by circumscribing it around a circle.

Comment: Alt. hint: the diagonals divide the rhombus into four triangles of equal area (which is in fact true for any parallelogram).

Comment: @dxiv, got it thanks :)

Comment: If $C$ is the center of the circle, $CF$ is perp to $AB'$ and $CD$ is perp to $A'B$ and $F, C$ and $D$ are collinear. As $CF = CD$ and $AF = A'D$, $A, C$ and $A'$ are also collinear with $AC = A'C$. Hence $C$ is also the intersection of the diagonals.

Comment: A rhombus has reflection symmetry on both diagonals. Therefore, so must the inscribed circle. From that it must follow that both diagonals are diameters of the circle.

Comment: @Sunaina, your way of solution is wrong, because F is not defined in terms of rombus without the circle. Math Lover proposed fine solution in comment (you can change C to E according your original question).